# top n queries using the offset clause

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT last_name 
FROM employees
order by last_name DESC
fetch first 5 rows only;
```

I am a beginner in SQL. I am trying to run this query but keep getting an error

> sql command not properly ended

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 1):

### oracle version < 12

```
  select * from 
        (select last_name, row_number() over(order by last_name desc nulls last) rnm
           from employees) 
   where rnm<=5;
```

### oracle version 12

```
SELECT last_name 
  FROM employees
 ORDER BY last_name DESC
OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```